# Private Data member is inaccessible in Friend Function

Tags: c++, friend, friend-function

The private data member is inaccessible. Although i have declared function as friend of class. 
Can anyone help me.

```
    class ONE;
    class TWO {
    public:
           void print(ONE& x);
    };

    class ONE {
    private:
            int a, b;    
    public:       
            friend void TWO::print(ONE& x);
            ONE() : a(1), b(2) { }
    };

    void TWO::print(ONE& x) {
         cout << "a is " << x.a << endl;
         cout << "b is " << x.b << endl;
    }

    int main() {
        ONE xobj;
        TWO yobj;
        yobj.print(xobj);
    }
```

Error Picture is attached.

[image: Private Data member inaccessible]

Comment: works in gcc 6.3:  https://ideone.com/uFov6b  Also, works in VS2017

Comment: The code compiles [just fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QGmek3InTQGDa90b), and that's not a compiler error.

Comment: Can't reproduce in MSVS2015 or 2010

Comment: Have you actually built it? Those looks like Intellisense _errors_ which is where the compiler is just guessing at things, but if you build it it should build fine.

Comment: If it's really an intellisense error: Intellisense (AKA Dumbisense) often is wrong (although it has become a lot better the last years). The occasional wrong wiggly lines in the code drawn by Intellisense are easy to ignore, but when the wrong errors show up in the error list, they become really confusing. That's why I never have Intellisense errors shown in the Error list (you can switch it off with the dropdown menu right to "0 Messages"

Comment: I'm also using MVS10 and MVS15, 2
ERROR is generated there.

Comment: Error is generated only MVS13 and MVS15, i used MVS10 error is not generated. It ran smooth. 
Why is it so?